# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present with JavaScript fetch request

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to make this fetch request to the user interface api using react:

```
const newpost = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.accessToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    apiName: "Contact",
    fields: {
      FirstName: this.state.firstName,
      LastName: this.state.lastName,
      Email: this.state.email,
    },
  }),
};

fetch("https://my_instance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/ui-api/records", newpost)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => console.error("error", error));
```

And am receiving this error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://my_instance.my.salesforce.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I am able to bypass the issue by installing the [moesif CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US) so I know my code works, but that isn't a practical fix for production.

I've tried running my project through https local to see if that was the cause, and I've also whitelisted my origin URL through salesforce but the error persists.

Has anyone else had any experience with this and were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Can you post your fetch code?

Comment: Hi yes sure, I have edited my OP to show the request

Comment: It should work according to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/extend_code_cors.htm. The UI API is supported. Can you double check the whitelisted URL follow what's described in this resource?

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes this is the same way I did it. I am still seeing the error...

Comment: I've seen this comment in the trailblazer community "I had similar use case, was able to do CORS request from angular to salesforce by making my server entry in "remote sites" as well as Salesforce "CORS". https only entries would yield desired result." https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BI96IAG - Can you try it out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried adding my url to the remote site settings but I am still receiving this error

Comment: Hi, did you resolve it ? I am facing the same issue!